# Spring batch Scheduling using ESP Scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to schedule spring batch jobs using ESP Scheduler. Can we even do it or not?

One of the solutions is that we can make rest endpoints to start job, and poll the results after some time - Can we do better than this?

I have explored the possibilities that we can do it with Spring Cloud Data Flow. But how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch-job is a workflow made of steps and transitions. You can orchestrate a direct-acyclic graph with the programming model. A common method to schedule batch-jobs is via the webhook mechanism provided by the schedulers. You would have to review ESP whether or not it includes support for it.

Once you have the batch-job registered and defined as a Task in SCDF, you will get a REST-API (in SCDF), which can be used to trigger the launch of the batch-job. The REST-API can be used in the scheduler (via webhook) to invoke the endpoint upon a recurring schedule.